# java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter id is null

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, jsf-2.2

I am reading a Java EE 7 book "Java EE 7 Recipes" by Josh Juneau. I am trying to run some sample code from chapter 3 (Recipe 3.5 ) to test the conditional navigation. The code is very simple and straightforward but unfortunately I am getting very odd behavior.

JSF Page script is given below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Login Test</title>
</h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="resourceTest">            
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <h:commandButton id="loginButton" action="#{loginTest.login}" value="Login" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and the JSF Managed Bean:

```
package com.test.controller;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginTest {

private boolean authenticated;

public LoginTest() {
    authenticated = false;
}

public boolean isAuthenticated() {
    return authenticated;
}

public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
    this.authenticated = authenticated;
}

public void login(){
    setAuthenticated(true);
}


}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{loginTest.login}</from-action>
        <if>#{loginTest.authenticated}</if>
        <to-view-id>/faces/nextpage.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

When I click on the Login button it generates an exception *Argument Error: Parameter id is null*

Stacktrace is given below:

```
[2013-11-22T10:28:14.893+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1385116094893] [levelValue: 900] [[
Argument Error: Parameter id is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter id is null
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:425)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.getFlow(FlowHandlerImpl.java:89)
.....
.....
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
]]
[2013-11-22T10:28:14.909+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [FATAL] [jsf.context.exception.handler.log] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1385116094909] [levelValue: 1100] [[
JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Argument Error: Parameter id is null]]
[2013-11-22T10:28:14.909+0000] [glassfish 4.0] [FATAL] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1385116094909] [levelValue: 1100] [[
Argument Error: Parameter id is null
javax.faces.FacesException: Argument Error: Parameter id is null
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
..........
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter id is null
at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:425)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.getFlow(FlowHandlerImpl.java:89)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:1204)
....
]]
```

Am I missing something?

Furthermore, if I change the EL expression in my JSF page to *#{loginTest.login()}* (i.e. append parenthesis), I don't get any error message but the redirection doesn't work. Does this make any difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reproduced it. It's a bug in Mojarra which has the same grounds as [issue 3054](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3054) which I already reported earlier. If there's no flow document ID in the navigation case, the [`NavigationCase#getToFlowDocumentId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationCase.html#getToFlowDocumentId%28%29) returns an empty string, never `null`, yet the code is performing only a null check.

I've reported this bug as [issue 3087](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3087). The fix shall hopefully be in 2.2.5. In the meanwhile, your best bet is forgetting navigation cases and using implicit navigation. Edit the login method as follows:

```
public String login() {
    setAuthenticated(true);
    return "/faces/page.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

And get rid of that navigation case.

Comment: That make sense. However what about using parenthesis in the EL expressions after the function name. If I use parenthesis in the EL expression like "#{loginTest.login()}" It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Because it didn't match the `<from-action>` which is compared as a literal string. As you returned `void` from action method, and no navigation case matched, by default the same view is returned. If you edit the `<from-action>` to include the parentheses, then you'll see that it "works" (it'll still fail with the NPE, but it's at least matched :) ).